# Making a Numeric Variable Categoric

Tags: r, variables

I have a variable, glyhb, that is numeric from 2.85 to 16.11. How can I turn it into a categoric variable where everything under 5.7 is a category, everything from 5.7 to 6.4 is another, and a third with everything 6.5 or higher.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVJLn.png)

Comment: Best dupe I can find quicky: [R - cut by defined interval](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5746544/903061), maybe someone has a better duplicate?

Comment: @Gregor this one is quite similar. [specify-factor-levels-for-intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558129/specify-factor-levels-for-intervals)

Answer (score 4):

The function `cut()` divides a numerical vector into segments according to the values defined in the parameter `breaks`. In this case we can include the option `right=FALSE` to specify that the value 5.7 should belong to category 2 and that the value 6.5 should be assigned to category 3. The default is to include the value at the right boundary in the corresponding segment.

```
cut(glyhb, breaks=c(0,5.7,6.5,Inf), right=FALSE, labels=paste0("cat", c(1:3))
```

By default `cut()` returns a vector of categorical variables. We can specify the labels of these factors (the levels) with the option `labels`. In this case the levels `cat1`, `cat2`, and `cat3` have been chosen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using nested `ifelse`:

```
set.seed(999)
glyhb <- runif(100, 2.85, 16.11)
categorical_glyhb <- factor(ifelse(glyhb >= 6.5, 3, ifelse(glyhb >= 5.7, 2, 1)))
```